# How to use object spread with nested properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-redux

I'm trying to return the following in my reducer (react-redux) and it's giving me a syntax error:

```
return { ...state, loginForm.email: action.payload.email }

state = { loginForm: { email: '', password: '' } } so on
```

I have babel preset stage 0 installed and es2015. This works fine:

```
return { ..state, loginForm: action.payload }
```

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Error you are getting because of the this key:

```
loginForm.email
```

It's not a valid object key.

Write it like this:

```
return { 
    ...state, 
    loginForm: {
        ...state.loginForm,
        email: action.payload.email
    } 
}
```

Comment: ```    const obj = {
      one: {
        a: 'at level one',
        two: {
          b: 'at level two',
          three: {
            c: 'at level two',
            z: 'I want to use spread operator to update this'
          }
        }
      }
    }; ```

Comment: how to use in case like that?

Comment: @Nux, one possible way is to expand till that point, like this: `return {
  ...state,
  obj: {
    ...state.obj,
    one: {
      ...state.obj.one,
      two: {
        ...state.obj.one.two,
        three: {
          ...state.obj.one.two.three,
          z: newValue,
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`, another way could be use deep cloning then change that value.

Answer (score 0):

In JS, a key value of an object is either a String value or a Symbol value. [official docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Object)

Answer (score -6):

I think you want something like this:

```
{ ...state, loginForm: { email: action.payload.email } }
```

Comment: Not sure, this one would override `loginForm` completely and therefore remove the `password` property.

Comment: this will override whole state.loginForm object value

Comment: you need to spread the rest of the properties of email if you don't want to be overridden