# How to make the initial state prettier in the Context (more readable)

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React in my web App and would like to make my initial state more prettier to read.

For now, I have many global variables (AppContext) as follow :

```
const initialState = {
  variable1: false,
  variable2: [],
  ...
  variable500: "",
}
```

Can I make them categorized by adding objects, as follow

```
const initialState = {
  activity1: {
    variable1:true,
    variable2: ""
    ... 
  },
  activity2: {
    variable50:true,
    variable51:[],
    variable52:55,
    ... 
  },
  etc.
}
```

Any tips are welcomed ! Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes you can make them categorized by adding objects,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: initialState : {  
previous properties....
testingObject: {
    attribute1: true,
    attribute2: 0
  }
}
when I perform the following action, my state doesn't update the values,
  if (action.type === "EXECUTE_TESTING") {

    return {
      ...state,
      testingObject.attribute1:false,
    };
  }
How can I update attribute1 and 2 values

Comment: I found my response in the following thread :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47103028/how-to-use-object-spread-with-nested-properties